# PHP can't take more than one ternary operator?

Tags: php, html

Basically I have the following code:

```
<a href="<?php echo (!$isLoggedIn && !isset($_COOKIE['access_token'])) ? "connect.php" : isset($_GET['autoooooo']) ? "main.php?auto=true" :""?>"></a>
```

However when I `var_dump` `$isLoggedIn` and `$isset($_COOKIE['access_token'])` both are false (so through the ! in the `<?php?>` it gets true) and the `href` should be `connect.php`... but it always is `main.php?auto=true"`.`autoooooo` does not even exist (I just made it for testing) and `href` should actually be empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't nest ternary operations!!!!!

Comment: Alright.... can you please explain me why?

Comment: Look at it. It's a mess. How do you read that? Write code that is easy to read. That's *very* important.

Comment: my favourite quote is: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live. Code for readability."

Comment: Well I thought I should keep it as short as possible in PHP. I am new to it...  so thanks for the notice.. However, does it actually have any effect on my question?

Comment: `can you please explain me why?` For precisely the reason that it's giving you a problem here.... it's hard to read and understand, and non-intuitive.... even the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) warn about the dangers of nesting ternary operators

Comment: ...cos too often you'll end up on stackoverflow asking why your code isn't working?

Comment: I want to thank everyone who gave a good and helpful comment. I will stop using ?: now. :)

Comment: There's no problem with using a single ternary `?:`, in fact it can be pretty useful; the problems arise when you try nesting ternaries, and that's what you should always avoid

Comment: Also edited the title. `If-else` is a statement (or rather a control structure). `?:` is an operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php, the ternary operator (`?:`) associates left-to-right (unlike in C or perl where it associates right-to-left).

That means that it evaluates the first `test ? value 1 : value 2`, and then uses that result to determine which value of the second operator to use.

Your construct would work in C or perl, but in php, you need to add brackets around each subsequent ternary operator.

Also, for readability, I recommend you add quite a few newlines and indents in your code.

Comment: Alright.... I guess this should be the answer... I like, that you explained it.. I think that will help other users too.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets for your 2nd clause:

```
$b1 = false;
$b2 = false;
echo $b1 ? 'b1 true' : ($b2 ? 'b2 true' : 'all false') ;
```

Output:

```
all false
```

Comment: Worked.. thank you. However.... as other users suggested I will stop using nested ?: now as it can cause problems like this and is not really readable :)